# Why a writer could not for the specified extension in function in OpenCV?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

So, I wrote a small program to clone masks for 30k+ images. Every image and masks sample there are converted to jpeg format. However, when I'm trying to start a program it creates some masks and then stops, throwing an error written in the title. It is quiet strange that OpenCV can't create jpeg image, since it is a default format for it.
Question is: how to make OpenCV actually save those newly created masks? 
Here is the code:

```
folders = ["162", "204", "260", "1093", "3297", "5020", "10066", "10870", "10917", "11160", "11331", "17218", "19106", "19306", "19388"]
for folder in folders:
    print(folder)
    names = os.listdir(folder)
    os.chdir("%s/masks"%folder)
    image = cv2.imread("%s.jpeg"%folder)
    for name in names:
        print(name)
        cv2.imwrite(img=image, filename=name)
```

Comment: You shouldn't save masks as jpeg (lossy format) in the first place. Try using png (lossless) instead.

Comment: are you sure there are only jpg files in your dir? can you print `name` before the error?

Comment: Yeah, only jpegs. Double-checked that.

Comment: Make sure the forward slashes are properly added, I think it's a path problem. In case it isn't, what is the output of `python -c "import cv2; print(cv2.getBuildInformation())" | grep -i jpeg`?